# get a hidden div to display below a table cell when the table cell is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that I want to appear directly below a table cell when the table cell is clicked.  Here is a sample of my code so far...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleDownloadSelectionDialog(divToggle,divId,event){
        pos_x = event.offsetX?(event.offsetX):event.pageX-document.getElementById(divToggle).offsetLeft;
        pos_y = event.offsetY?(event.offsetY):event.pageY-document.getElementById(divToggle).offsetTop;

        alert(pos_y+"  "+pos_x+" "+divId);

        document.getElementById(divId).style.top = pos_y;
        document.getElementById(divId).style.left = pos_x;
        document.getElementById(divId).style.display = 'block';

    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="div_downloadDialog" id="div_hidden1" style="display: none; top: 0; left: 0; position: absolute;">This div is hidden</div>

<table class="Oligo_Diversity">

<tr>
<td>blah</td><td>blah</td><td>blah</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><div id="div_toggle1" onclick="toggleDownloadSelectionDialog('div_toggle1','div_hidden1',event);">click here for download dialog</div></td>
<td>blah</td>
<td>blah</td>
</tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like the hidden download div to appear directly below the table cell it is clicked on.  My javascript seems to get the position but I'm having trouble passing this information to the div.  Removing the DOCTYPE will make this work but for the project I'm working on I need a doctype.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `position: absolute` for the `DIV` as sv_in said.

This line also may cause troubles in IE:

```
pos_x = event.offsetX?(event.offsetX):event.pageX-document.getElementById(divToggle).offsetLeft;
```

If you'll run this in IE, ternary operator finds the condition true and returns `true` after `?`.

Switch the line to:

```
pos_x = (event.offsetX)?event.offsetX:event.pageX-document.getElementById(divToggle).offsetLeft;
```

And the same on next line for `pos_y`.

When using `<!DOCTYPE html>` also units have to be used in style definitions:

```
document.getElementById(divId).style.left = pos_x+'px';
document.getElementById(divId).style.top = pos_y+'px';
```

Comment: Adding the 'px' worked with the doctype.  Thank you.  It works pretty well now.  I just have to get the positioning corrected but at least now it's not hanging on the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than messing with absolute positioning, I suggest you use the css display attribute to show or hide your div. This will allow the html to automatically position the div. Here is some example code:

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function expand(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    }
    function hide(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table><tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <div style="cursor:pointer" onclick="expand('expand1')">Click to Expand td 1</div>
        <div id="expand1" style="cursor:pointer;display:none" onclick="hide('expand1')">
            Click to  hide td 1 expansion
        </div>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <div style="cursor:pointer" onclick="expand('expand2')">Click to Expand td 2</div>
        <div id="expand2" style="cursor:pointer;display:none" onclick="hide('expand2')">
            Click to hide td 2 expansion
        </div>
    </td>
</tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That also worked very well.  Using this combined with Teemu's 'px' suggestion has everything working perfectly.  I wish I could give you both accepted answers.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

set `position:absolute` as well to the div. Also `z-index` would be good, if needed. :)
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp